# Find words in many files

Tags: linux, command-line, find, grep

I am looking for this `struct messages_sdd_t` and I need to search through a lot of *.c files to find it. However, I can't seen to find a match as I want to exclude all the words 'struct' and 'messages_sdd_t'. As I want to search on this only 'struct messages_sdd_t' The reason for this is, as struct is used many times and I keep getting pages or search results.

I have been doing this without success:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | xargs grep 'struct messages_sdd_t'
```

and this

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | xargs egrep -w 'struct|messages_sdd_t'
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/):

> ack "struct messages_sdd_t" *.c

It is recoursive by default and it is a lot faster than `grep` (according to my observation) when searching trough a directory containing tons of source code.

If you don't want to use `ack`, `grep` should be fine too:

> grep -r "struct messages_sdd_t" *.c

Comment: Definitely +1 for making me realize, after all those long years, that grep has a -r option...

Comment: "grep -r" is a really good answer. The problem with find | xargs is that if there are many files, you will get an "argument list too long" error message.  You can use the -n switch for xargs to avoid this, but then you should set the -H switch for grep so you can be sure that it prefixes the filename. There is one advantage of using "find | xargs" instead of "grep -r": you can make arbitrary filter for the files you want to search.

Comment: Ack recognizes C as a filetype.  Use "ack 'struct messages_sdd_t' --cc", and it will find all C files, including .h header files.

Comment: @petersohn: `xargs` does not fail in this way. It uses the system value of maximum argument length and splits accordingly. Run `xargs --show-limits` to see what it uses on your specific system. If one needs to use `find`, it is also good to see the `-exec command {} +` construct in the manual which will more or less emulate `xargs` directly in the find command, with as few sub process invocations as possible.

Comment: @ant2009: The given answer is incorrect since it will **not** search recursively when given file names as arguments like this. It will only search through the `.c` files in the current directory, not sub directories.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep 'struct\s\+messages_sdd_t' {} \;
```

Or if you only care about the filename:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -q 'struct\s\+messages_sdd_t' {} \; -print
```

Comment: in this case `xargs` might be better than `-exec`; -exec will spawn one grep process for each file.

Comment: No, exec doesn't do that - `{} \;` does. If you use `{} +`, multiple files will be processed by a single grep process.

Comment: How about `grep -l` instead of `grep -q -print`?

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -R --include='*.c' 'struct messages_sdd_t' .
```

This will search recursively and use `grep` itself to pick only `.c` files.

Consider adding `-H` to always write the file name with the line match.